How to fix active signal resolution for Windows 11 VM?
I am running a Windows 11 guest via virt-manager kvm on Ubuntu 22.94. My Windows display resolution is set as 1920x1080, but the active signal resolution is showing as 600x480 and the refresh rate is showing as unknown. I am using qxl driver and spice server on virt-viewer. Spice guest tool for Windows is also installed. Please help to bring up the active signal resolution to 1920x1080.
